# How do I duplicate last 10 entries in a range ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Simply put I will have 16 rows of data going from A1:A16 in Column B I want to display ONLY the last 10 entries while ignoring blanks.
This is a weekly entry so at first there are a lot of blanks.
For instance if there are 6 entries a1 to a6 the B column would list all 6 but if there are 13 entries a1 to a13 I want the B column to display only the last 10 from A4 to A13

I'm using free 365 version. I have tried index but it includes blank cells and I need the formula to ignore them until values are filled in.

Comment: try adding unique() to your function then sort()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `TAKE()` with `TOCOL()` function. Try-

```
=TAKE(TOCOL(A:A,1),-10)
```

Here argument `-10` of `TAKE()` function indicate keep 10 entries from bottom to top.

[image]

Comment: This is doing the same thing the index function was. Perhaps it's important to say the cells in the A column have formulas in them that will auto fill the cells as data is entered elsewhere on the sheet...your formula works perfectly if I copy and paste as values and run the formula on that data set but not when I run it on cells with formulas.

Comment: @uncleuhls no blanks shown in column B so not sure what you mean or what you got wrong.

Comment: I think it's because the blank cells in Column A are not truly blank and contain formulas? If I use the Take and TOCOL functions on a copy and pasted list(as values) it works fine.

Comment: @uncleuhls Then use `=TAKE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),-10)`.

Comment: Sure, did I do it? I only saw 1 check mark and nothing that pertained to your answer being correct

Comment: @uncleuhls Yes, that check mark did it.